# Deploying a CLR Assembly to a different database than the rest of the objects

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-data-tools, sqlclr, sqlcmd

I am using Visual Studio and a SQL Server Database Project to maintain my database objects through TFS. I have implemented a CLR Assembly for using RegEx Pattern matching in my UnitTests. I want to deploy this CLR to a different database than where the rest of the objects in the database would be deployed to.

- `Database_1` - contains all of the database objects
- `Database_2` - contains the CLR Assembly and UDFs for RegEx Pattern Matching.

I would like to create the script to deploy a CLR Assembly and related UDFs to one database, while creating the script which will deploy the rest of the changes to another database.  I would like to do this using PRE/POST scripts using `sqlcmd` as I think this is the easiest way to do this.

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you actually need it to be in a separate database? You could look at doing a composite project (2 projects, 2 dacpacs, 1 database), and deploy everything to your unit test environment, but only the "real" code to your "real" environment,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Publishing to another Database requires a different Database Project. They should be able to be in the same solution, but having two different Database projects will allow for different publishing properties (e.g. Target Database, etc).

OR, a very quick and easy to not worry about any of that would be to use the [SQL#](http://SQLsharp.com/) SQLCLR library of functions (which I wrote). The free version of SQL# contains several RegEx functions as well as many others. You can just save the installation script (once the correct Database name has been edited into the `USE` statement) into TFS and be done with it :-).

Comment: +1 for needing to use a different database project. not actually upvoted though because I don't know your library so not sure if I would recommend or not.

Comment: Marked as answer.  I ended up creating another Database Project for the SQLCLR solution.  Since this will only be used during testing, and on a test server, I am able to deploy it to the test server when necessary, and it able to be referenced in my Database Unit Tests.